# what does it mean when "> is returned on command line?

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm trying to export a table to csv form using mysql.  I enter the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM fields INTO OUTFILE ‘/tmp/fields.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,' ENCLOSED BY ‘"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

then the system returns:

">

What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you

Comment: It means the previous command is not complete, the console expects you to continue with the command. That typically happens with unbalanced quote chars. In your case it is the first one before the `/tmp...` that is actually _not_ a quote char. You are trying to use different chars for that purpose which does not work. Watch that. Note: `‘` differs from `'`.

Comment: Look out for the wildcard `*`.